# Moving a Label/ImageIcon with Arrow Keys Using Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, awt

I'm trying to move the playerLbl object every time the arrow keys are pressed.
I have been trying to use the `repaint()` method with the `keyPressed()` method. I'm not sure if there are missing methods to implement. Is my `LayeredPane` causing the issue? Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code:
**Board.java**

```
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class Board {

    int x = 20;
    int y = 500;
    final int width = 150;
    final int height = 150;

    // Initializes a window to open
    Board() {

        // Create a game window
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Game");
        JLayeredPane layers = new JLayeredPane();

        // Create a layered pane to add images on top of each other
        layers.setBounds(0, 0, 1010, 760);

        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setBounds(0, 0, 1010, 760);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        // Create background image
        JLabel backgroundLbl = new JLabel();
        ImageIcon background = new ImageIcon("sampleImage.png");
  
        // Set the labels picture and size
        backgroundLbl.setIcon(background);
        backgroundLbl.setBounds(0, 0, 1010, 760);
          
        // Get the player image and resize
        ImageIcon playerImage = new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon("character.jpg").getImage().getScaledInstance(100, 100, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
        JLabel playerLbl = new JLabel();
  
        // Add picture to label and locate starting position
        playerLbl.setIcon(playerImage);
        playerLbl.setBounds(x, y, width, height);

        // Add player image and background to Layer Panel
        layers.add(backgroundLbl, Integer.valueOf(0));
        layers.add(playerLbl, Integer.valueOf(1));

        frame.add(layers);
        
        // Add KeyListener
        frame.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

            // Checks what key was pressed
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

                // get the key pressed
                int key  = e.getKeyCode();

                // If arrow key is pressed, redraw the image to new coordinates?
                if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
                    playerLbl.repaint(x--, y, width, height);
                }
                else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
                    playerLbl.repaint(x++, y, width, height);
                }
                else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
                    playerLbl.repaint(x, y++, width, height);
                }
            }

            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

            }

            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use a KeyListener. Instead use `Key Bindings`. See: [Motion Using the Keyboard](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/) for more information and working examples.

Comment: `frame.setLayout(null);` Expect problems. This is a case for custom painting, so I won't give my usual spiel about using layout managers..